# PHP check image if exists and return a text if not

Tags: php, php-curl, getimagesize

I found this solution, because `@getimagesize` was horrible slow:

```
function get_image_by_id($ID)
{
$url = $ID;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
if(file_get_contents($url) == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
else
{
    return $url;
}
}
```

It works very fast but this function always tries to load the image even if it isn't exists. Here is how I implement into my code:

```
<?php if (get_image_by_id($link)): ?>
    <?php echo '<img src="' . $link . '" alt="' . $propname . '" />'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need an else only if the image isn't exists then only echo `$propname` from the array.

With `is_null` it works but it has the same speed as `@getimagesize` (slow).

So now the else looks like:

```
<?php if (is_null(get_image_by_id($link))): ?>
    <?php echo $propname; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I make a fast code to this:

```
if(image_exists($link) {
echo $image;
} else {
echo $propname;
}
```

Comment: is URL in  `file_get_contents($url)` the URL to the image?

Comment: @Edwin yes it is the url for the image

Answer (score 2):

**Use Curl for returning status to identify existence of image**

```
<?php
    function image_exist($url){
        $ch = curl_init($url);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($code == 200){
           $status = true;
        }else{
          $status = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
       return $status;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If I understand well it has 2 status to return. A true if the image exists on the link and a false if not?

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see the curl response and if you have something then do your code:

```
$output=curl_exec($ch);
if ($output === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
  //$output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
  //if (curl_error($ch))
  //  $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
  //}
  return null; //or $output
else {
  // 'OK' status; format $output data if necessary here: 
  return $url;
}
```

don't forget to close the curl connection `curl_close($ch);`